# How can Necromancers live in hiding today?

Tags: fantasy-races

I have this question, how could possibly Necromancers live today within our world without revealing themselves as Necromancers?

Taking into consideration that they have all their accessories and their culture, structures and magic.

EDIT:

By Necromancers I mean absolutely everything, starting with raising the dead and talking to spirits, to conjuring blood golems and using dark magic linked to death and the dead.

They use such accessories as skulls, bones, blood, staves, books, dark creatures and much more.

Necromancers are widespread and in some countries they have their big buildings that are situated underground. With these buildings the common problem is the plague it erupts, which spreads and spoils the soil.

How could Necromancers hide, explain, conceal this plague?

How can Necromancers walk the world without suspicion for ordinary people but still staying themselves? I was thinking about cloaks...

EDIT 2:

Okay, so here's is whst I approximately have in mind. In today's world there exist Necromancers who have a foe as strong as them (this is already set). Among Necromancers there are less evil ones and neutral ones. Most Necromancers live either as families or alone trying ti conceal their identities and blend in as much as possible. Those who have dived less into the darkest of necromancy art are more human to the eye than those who have, the latter are closer to the dead and their world.

Necromancers have sort of clans around the world. The evil Necromancers (the majority) need plague grounds to work on, cemeteries with rotten flesh, no flowers and different other features depending on what they want. If a Necromancer needs a clay golem, he needs to get that from somewhere, if he needs a bunch of skeleton warriors he needs a cemetery. Every necromancy magic requires certain items, skills, will and something else.

Necromancers aren't afraid of light but prefer the dark, they need staves to do most magic, but some can be done without it - everything depends on the magic. Blood magic requires blood, some magic requires flesh, bones, spirits.

Necromancers get weaker the more magic they do, the harder the magic the quicker the exhaustion. Necromancers can be women, men and children. Some humans know about them, most don't.

Comment: What accessories? What culture? What magic? (To have a "culture", for example, means that there are many of them, and they interact sufficiently often.)

Comment: Why do you ask such questions? It doesn't matter.

Comment: I think these questions will help us to understand the world you are trying to build, don't worry take your time to consider them. Here everybody have a drink  tap water is cool and refreshing and I think the bars are closed.

Comment: The question definitely needs more focus on the definition of "necromancers". Your edit involving cloaks to hide in plain sight suggest that you are thinking about a kind of necromancer which would look clearly non-human at first sight, and I doubt anyone but you would make that assumption instintively. We can't read your mind, and the image of a necromancer that you have seems to be very specific. Please explain a little bit more your setting and your characters so we can re-open the question and answer properly.

Comment: @Rekesoft Okay, I'll try, however I have no idea what I want

Comment: Errrrr... If you don't know what you want, how are you going to choose the right answer? Worse, how can we expect to answer if you don't know exactly what you want answered?

Comment: @Rekesoft I need some concept where  any kind of Necromancers live among humans in whatever way there can be. I am looking for options to choose from.

Comment: If I were to know what I wanted then I wouldn't ask this question I'd simply know what to do.

Comment: I really like the idea that monster creating, plague-causing wizards with big terrifying buildings hide among ordinary folks by using cloaks.  +1!  I hope this reopens soon because it is a great concept.

Comment: If it doesn't matter than any answer is equally valid, which is one the cases where our [help] states being a type of question one should avoid asking here

Answer (score 7):

#### As a tax exempt religion with admission requirements

Set up a religion of your own, be closed about the exact details of your rituals, but open about your community and social networks.

Legally, you're basically a religion with different words, stricter entrance requirements and the holy artifacts under a bit more security.

Comment: Okay, I will edit the question a bit

Comment: @SovereignSun please don't edit the equestion such that it invalidates existing answers. The time to make big edits is when you use the sandbox.

Comment: I'm not sure what to make of the edits "and they have buildings underground that have plagues" and "they're not themselves if they walk the world but maybe can hide with cloaks", seems like a second question.

Answer (score 5):

https://voodoomuseum.com/

Welcome to the Museum of Voodoo!

Here our extremely knowledgeable staff will enthrall you with tales of necromancy and intrigue from the storied history of Louisiana. All our professors are graduates of our in house anthropology Doctorate program. A education so prestigious that we hand pick our applicants. Furthermore, we are continuously expanding our collection to include new items recently discovered and host exhibits from our sister sites in the Satanist museum of Russia, and the Animalist museums in the Republic of Congo. We ask the small children stay away from the main exhibits as some of the pieces have been restored to the point where they appear to still have blood on them. This is because we spare no expense in our reproductions! Book a tour now with a family or ask for our special private after hours tours. We also offer spooky tarot readings and burial services in the old Hattian tradition.

We foretell your ultimate doom! At the Voodoo Museum!

OPEM 10AM TO 6PM
SEVEN DAYS A WEEK
OPEN MOST HOLIDAYS

ADMISSIONS:
$10 ADULTS 
$8 SENIOR, MILITARY, & STUDENTS
FREE ENTRANCE TO THE GIFT SHOP

Essentially the necromancers know nobody believes in necromancy, so displaying their artifacts in public is not actually a risk. They become museum curators who teach new necromancers instead of giving them a doctorate education. They store all their artifacts in museum storage and claim they are holding them for a future exhibition. If the artifact is seen being used in a crime they ship them off to another museum on a different continent. Sure, your detective might find the sacrificial knife in the Detroit African religious histories museum, but good luck finding it in Scotland's Fae museum's storage hall a week after the crime when it is filed under The Bean Nighe's totems.

Answer (score 3):

**Alternative Pharma**

What the necromancers need is a pharmaceutical corporation front linked to a front religion that rejects conventional medical science. Reliance on "faith healing" should help justify their total seclusion and simultaneously, provide the raison d'etre for their pharmacorp's existence("holy science"). If the real world Followers of Christ denomination [can get away with it, so can you.](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2016/apr/13/followers-of-christ-idaho-religious-sect-child-mortality-refusing-medical-help)

Plagues in the soil can be explained away by the corporate front as an industrial accident. You'll probably need additional means to deflect the occasional regulatory probing, like bribery or zombie "recruitment". It might also help to propose an "Alternative Parenthood Clinic System"; after all, it's easy to raise a family when they're all buried together.

Comment: I can't believe you ended with a joke, and a dark one at that.

Comment: Great answer, though, I like how it used a IRL example!